# Tools to debug slow NFS on OSX

Tags: osx, nfs, io, dtrace, nexenta

I have 2 mac pros connected to a Nexenta NAS. They have a fast network connection, the same ping time, and the routes to the server are the same (both are plugged into the same switch).

One computer has very slow reads and writes on the NAS when the files are larger that about 20 KB (found with `ioping`). It responds to ping, doesn't drop packets, it can be accessed with SSH and works fine.I've checked the network over that interface and as far as I can tell there is nothing wrong unless I am connecting to the NAS **with NFS specifically**.

**What tools are available on Mac OS to understand NFS performance problems?**

Comment: `tcpdump` with `-ttt` for delta timestamps is worth a look.  Record the NFS packets between server1+NAS, and then between server2+NAS, and compare the output.

Comment: Have you verified that only NFS is affected?  Maybe the problem isn't NFS, but only appears when you try sending larger chunks of data in relatively short periods of time. What's the performance between the various systems if you try other ways of moving relatively large amounts of data between them?  Try various protocols such as netcat, scp, and ftp.